# Save File to MyDocuments + App Folder

Tags: c#, file, append, savefiledialog, appsettings

I am trying to save my .NET application settings file to the user's %MyDocument%\MyApplication folder, but I don't know how to check for an existing folder\file, and create or append the folder\file on save.  I don't want to open a saveFileDialog because I need the file to be in the same place on all user computers.  This is what I have so far, but it isn't working.  Any help would be appreciated:

```
var saveSettings = settingsList.text;  //assign settings to a variable
saveSettings = Regex.Replace(saveSettings, @"\s+", "").Trim() + Environment.NewLine; //remove any extra spaces and add a carriage return so that each setting is on a new line            

var fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments + "\\MyApp\\", "settings.dat");  //generate path to settings.dat
File.AppendAllText(fileName, saveSettings);  //save settings.dat
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `Directory.Exist()' method for the folder or if you know the full path you can check the `File.Exist()` method also why are you using `RegEx.Replace` when you can use the built in `string.Replace()` method..  also your `string.Format("{0}\\{1}"` isn't that putting an extra 2 backslashes`\\` in your path..?

Comment: the "\\" is needed to escape the "\"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDoc‌​uments),"MyApp","settings.dat");

if(Directory.Exists(path))
{
    //Exists
}
else
{
    //Needs to be created
}
```

Comment: CC...do you know how to set the path to the default MyDocs directory?  My build is creating a new MyDocuments folder in my \bin\Debug\folder.

Comment: @Jeagr I think I see why, check my answer

Comment: You should use `string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),"MyApp","settings.dat");`

Answer (score 3):

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(path)); //you don't need to check if it exists first