# Creating Directory for the Uploaded files in C#

Tags: c#, file-upload, file-io

How can I possibly make a directory or folder for the uploaded files in C# program? I want to upload files like PDF and store it in `my documents>my_folder`.

Also, I want to check if the folder exist then it wont create but if not, it will create a new folder inside the my documents folder.

Comment: Check out this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to create a directory

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("path");
```

And use:

```
System.IO.Directory.Exists("path")
```

to check if the folder exists already.

The first one will create the folder while the second one will return `true` or `false`, based on which you should do your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do the creation check

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("path");
```

This Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new
>   directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing
>   directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [Save File to MyDocuments + App Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865963/save-file-to-mydocuments-app-folder) which describes how to check for a subfolder in the My Documents folder. If it fails the check you can then use `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` to create your folder.